# How to use OAuth 1.0a signature generator with Angular2+

Tags: angular, oauth

I am going to create Angular application for working with flickr. So I need to generate a signature for a consumer. It is seemed to me, that the best way is to install  oauth 1.0a signature generator . So I have done it "npm i oauth-signature". But I do not not know how to use it correctly. I mean - should I add any information  to angular.json or package.json files? Any Dependency Injections? How to use oauthSignature.generate() method in a proper way? -

Answer (score 1):

If you run this command, then you don't need to change angular.json or package.json file.

```js
npm i oauth-signature --save
```

Next step is to import it in your ts file. Like this,

```html
import * as oauth from 'oauth-signature';
```

then call oauthSignature.generate method.

Comment: Thank you very mach for answer. It works. But unfortunately when I try to use the generated signature with flickr I receive error "oauth_problem=signature_invalid". Have no idea how to fix it